# Involutive fourier transform

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, reference-request, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

The writer [here](http://www.numericana.com/answer/fourier.htm) states

> I am introducing a viewpoint  (the involutive convention)  which makes the Fourier transform its own inverse  (i.e., the Fourier transform so defined is an  involution).

If I am reading the notation correctly, the definition given is:

$$F(f)(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(2\pi is x)\overline{f(x)}dx.$$

Under this convention, $F$ fails to be a linear operator; but, I don't think this is too big of a deal, since $F$ ends up being [conjugate-linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear_map). In any event, I have never seen this definition before. My question is, firstly, does it have any subtle issues that make it a bad idea? If not, a thoughtful discussion of the benefits of this definition would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not a linear operator.

Comment: @WimC, good point. $F(af) = \bar{a}F(f)$. Do you know whether or not this is a big deal? It *is* linear if we restrict our attention to $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @WimC, according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilinear) article I just found at wikipedia, the property $F$ possesses is called "antilinearity."

Comment: @user18921 Wouldn't the property be more accurately described as the conjugate symmetry of the inner product? The typical definition of the fourier transform can be thought of as the inner product of $f$ and the character $e^{-2\pi i s x}$.

Comment: @user18921 Just a disclaimer that I am still a student. But the antilinearity seems to make more sense as conjugate symmetry of an inner product. You could instead then write $F(af) = \langle e^{2\pi i s x}, a\overline{f}\rangle = \langle \overline{a}f, e^{-2\pi i s x}\rangle = \overline{a} \langle f, e^{-2\pi i s x}\rangle = \langle e^{2\pi i s x }, \overline{f}\rangle = \overline{a}F(f). $

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this in an antilinear transformation and not a linear one is a slight drawback. As a consequence, **Parseval's formula fails**:
$$
\langle \mathcal{F}(f),\mathcal{F}(g)\rangle = \overline{\langle f,g\rangle}
$$
in other words: **The transform is not unitary any more.** (It still preserves the $L^2$-norm, though.) This is annoying in many situations and I guess it also makes the involutive form unsuitable for many fields where unitarity is important like quantum mechanics (e.g. one had to adapt the momentum operator to keep the dual relationship of position and momentum).

To answer the question for reasons for its unpopularity: From a practical point of view there is no big advantage of the involutive form. Being its own inverse seems like a nice property but it does not really help with the daily use of the Fourier transform. I would even say that it is a slight advantage of the conventional Fourier transform that it is asymmetric - it helps to keep track on which side you are operating at the moment.

Remember that a new notion has to prove that its advantages largely outweigh the drawbacks to have is adapted by the community. In this case I do not see such an advantage and I am happy to stick with the usual Fourier transform…

Comment: Does the failure of Parseval's formula actually matter though? According to wikipedia, there's a notion of an [antiunitary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiunitary_operator).

Comment: What do you mean by "does it matter"? Of course you can make everything work, but you have to adapt every single instance where the Fourier transform used to be unitary. I would rather ask: Does it really matter that the involutive Fourier transform is an involution? Does that really help somewhere? I personally say no, so I stick with the usual definition. I thought I made clear why I think that many others think the same.

Comment: There is, in fact, an advantage to this form: it meshes well with the usual convention in mathematics and mechanics (but not thermodynamics) that the _Legendre_ transform be involutive, the Legendre transform being obtained from the Fourier transform via [Maslov dequantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Maslov+dequantization) (in the stationary phase approximation, to put it more prosaically). That is, I’d say that either one’s Fourier transform ought to be semilinear, or one’s Legendre transform ought to be order-4. (1/2)

Comment: Unfortunately, on one hand, I don’t think the theory of the _fractional_ Fourier transform can be reconciled with the semilinear convention, but on the other, an involutive convention for the Legendre(–Fenchel) transform makes more geometric sense in light of other convex dualities. I’d love to be proven wrong on either of these points. (2/2)

Comment: Hm. I didn’t think for look for it previously, but it seems that [there is in fact](https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/28/19/008) also a fractional Legendre transform (as, per Maslov, there must be) which also has to use the order-4 convention for the usual Legendre transform, not the geometrically natural involutive one. So one doesn’t have to use Fourier to see the problem.